# conditional probability and entropy

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, information-theory, entropy

There is a cafe that offers only coffee (C) and tea (T).  However, the size of the cup is large (L),
 medium (M) and small (S).  Let a random variable for type of drink {C,T } be X, and a random variable  for a value of cup size {L, M, S} be Y.

We know the following.

Joint distribution : $ Pr ({X= C, Y = L}) = 0.3 $

That is, the probability for
 the visitor to order a large cup of coffee is 0.3, which is a higher probability than any other combination of drink and cup.

$Pr ({X = T, Y = L}) = 0.1,$
$ Pr ({X = C, Y = M}) = Pr ({X = T, Y = S})$

.  $Entropy: H (X) = 1.0 bit,$
$ H (X | Y = S) = 0.469 bit. $

At this time, find $H (Y),$
$ H (X | Y), H (Y | X), H (X, Y), I (X; Y). $

I try to make the joint distribution table  
\begin{array}{rc} 
               & Y_{\text{size}} \\
X_{\text{type}} & \begin{aligned} 
\  P (X,Y )&& Y=\text{L} && Y=\text{M} && Y=\text{S} 
\\X=\text{coffee} &&\frac{3}{10} && \text{x} && \text{} && \text{0.5}  
\\ X=\text{Tea} &&\frac{1}{10}&&\frac{}{} && \text{x} && \text{0.5}  
\end{aligned}
\end{array}

i see from the entropy table that $ H (X) = 1.0 bit$, means p=0.5 and 1-p =0.5 
because $H(X)=plnp + (1-p)ln (1-p) =1$
but im stuck at ,$H (X|Y=s)=0.469$ bit from the table $H (X|Y=s)=0.469 = p lnp +(1-p)lnp$ will give $p = 0.1$ or $0.9$
but if i put it in table , p(x,s) it wont match, how can i find the probability $P(X=c,Y=s)$
hopefully someone could enlight me thank
and also log is in based 2

Comment: You know from the above that $P(X  = C, Y = S) = 0.2 - x$, so $P(Y = S) = 0.2,$ and thus  $P(X = C|Y = S) = 1 - 5x$. This means that $5x$ is $0.1$ or $0.9$, not $x$. Equivalently, $x$ is $0.02$ or $0.18$. But, if $x = 0.02,$ then $P(X = T, Y = M) = 0.4 - x = 0.38 > 0.3,$ which contradicts that a large coffee is the most probable order. This leaves you with $x = 0.18,$ at which point you have the full joint distribution.

Comment: @stochasticboy321　thankyou so much! you save my life !